# How to go about compiling opencv for 32bit for visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, 32-bit

I've been trying to get the 32bit compilation of opencv but am struggling to do so. I have followed the tutorial [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html) but with still no success.
I already installed all mentioned programs in the tutorial. It seems the tutorial is outdated with broken links. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe an already built 32bit mirror somewhere I missed?
I followed all steps meticulously. Intel Threading Building Blocks (TBB) I could not find within the tutorial. In the end I got left with the below message and no visual studio solution to build the libraries.

Following is the message I'm getting in CMake

this is the whole message

```
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "3.4")
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (Required is at least version "3.2")
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
at: C:/Users/Hadi/Downloads/opencccv/opencv/sources/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win
found Intel IPP IW sources: 2017.0.3
at: C:/Users/Hadi/Downloads/opencccv/opencv/sources/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_win
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Could NOT find Pylint (missing: PYLINT_EXECUTABLE) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
Excluding from source files list: C:/Users/Hadi/Downloads/opencccv/opencv/sources/build/modules/imgproc/accum.neon.cpp
Torch importer has been enabled. To run the tests you have to install Torch ('th' executable should be available) and generate testdata using opencv_extra/testdata/dnn/generate_torch_models.py script.

General configuration for OpenCV 3.3.1 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2017-11-16T09:33:32Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.14393 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.9.4
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2
      requested:                 SSE2
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2
      SSE4_1 (3 files):          + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (2 files):            + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (8 files):            + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++11:                       YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24215.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /fp:fast   /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP8  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /fp:fast   /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP8  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /fp:fast   /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2   /MP8  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG  /Zi
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /fp:fast   /arch:SSE /arch:SSE2   /MP8  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:X86  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml objdetect photo video dnn imgcodecs shape videoio highgui superres ts features2d calib3d stitching videostab
    Disabled:                    js world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.24)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    GDAL:                        NO
    GDCM:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.89.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.71.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.58.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.6.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 3.5.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO
    Intel Media SDK:             NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use Intel IPP:               2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
               at:               C:/Users/Hadi/Downloads/opencccv/opencv/sources/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win
    Use Intel IPP IW:            sources (2017.0.3)
                  at:            C:/Users/Hadi/Downloads/opencccv/opencv/sources/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_win
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
    Include path:                C:/Users/Hadi/Downloads/opencccv/opencv/sources/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 (ver 2.7.14)

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Python (for build):            

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:
    mex:                         C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/mex.bat
    Compiler/generator:          Not working (bindings will not be generated)

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

Comment: It's moaning about inability to find python and intel IPP do you need the python bindings if you're only interested in c++ dlls, also we don't know what you really did, claiming you followed some tutorial doesn't tell us where you went wrong

Comment: Actually none of the above are error messages!!, you should post all your CMake output. That is only OpenCV CMake looking for everything to see what options can or not be enabled. For example, if no python interpreter is found like the messages here, it will disable python module compilation.

Comment: Do you need to compile openCV, or do you need to use the openCV library? because you could just install it from nuget.

Comment: I read your cmake output, and there is NOTHING that indicates that there is an error. And actually it says "Configuring done", Now you must click the "Generate" button in the cmake gui and it will generate in the build folder a .sln file which you can open with visual studio

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. So strange I have used CMake before with no problem and thought I had pressed generate the first time but I guess not?